# Komma bei „so früh wie nach … möglich“?

Tags: comma, comparison

In http://www.lifesteyl.de/inhalt/die-besten-filme steht:

> Und vielleicht reicht es ja schon, wenn man als junger Mensch die Episode IV so früh wie nach Altersbeschränkung eben möglich im Kino gesehen hat.

Ich dachte, „so früh wie nach Altersbeschränkung eben möglich“ enthält ein ellipsiertes „es … ist“, also eigentlich eine Verkürzung von „so früh, wie es nach Altersbeschränkung eben möglich ist, …“ darstellt. Trotzdem sehe ich keine Kommata im Zitat. Wie ist es richtig™? Bitte mit Erklärung und Regleverweis.

Answer (score 2):

In der Wendung

> so früh wie möglich

ist *wie* eine vergleichende Konjunktion. Gemäß § 74, E3 des [Amtlichen Regelwerks 2018](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/6201) gilt explizit:

> **E3:** Vergleiche mit als oder wie in Verbindung mit einer Wortgruppe oder einem Wort sind keine Nebensätze; entsprechend setzt man kein Komma […]